# Is there a way to remove a LinkedIn Connection via Javascript

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to find a way to remove a LinkedIn connection via Javascript using the connection ID. It's not possible via the Connections API (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api).

LinkedIn does it on its own site via a form. Is there a way to replicate that functionality?

Comment: You've answered your own question: "It's not possible via the API"

Comment: I know it's not possible via API. I was not asking about the API. LinkedIN does it on its own site via a form. I was asking if there is  a way to replicate that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about JS on a web browser? In that case, posting to the form via JS is probably considered CSRF and will be blocked by a modern browser. So no, likely not possible from a modern browser.

If you're using node.js or another non-browser JS, then you could just do normal HTTP requests to sign in, handle the session cookie, and post to the form.

Comment: I was hoping for an easier way out. I'm trying to build a browser extension to make removing connections from LinkedIn easier.

Comment: Oh, well, a browser extension is probably a different matter. Assuming you're building for Firefox, check their documentation for doing arbitrary HTTP from extensions. You basically want to log the user into linkedin, retain the session cookie, then post to their form using that cookie. I haven't used the linkedin API but I've also never used an API that has the same authorization process as the browser service, so arbitrary HTTP is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
function stepOne(){

document.querySelector('button.mn-connection-card__dropdown-trigger.artdeco-button--tertiary.artdeco-button--muted.artdeco-button--circle.p1.artdeco-dropdown__trigger.artdeco-dropdown__trigger--placement-bottom.ember-view').click();
window.zorro++;


setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('button.display-flex').click();
    window.zorro++;

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector('button.artdeco-button--primary').click();
        window.zorro++;

        if(window.zorro % 3 == 0)
            setTimeout(function () {
                stepOne();
            }, 6000);

        }, 300);

}, 300);



}

window.zorro = 0;
stepOne();
```

Comment: works properly on Googke Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the console from https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/:

```
var i;
for (i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
    $("span[class='mn-connection-card__dropdown-option-text ml1']")[i].click();
    $("button[data-control-name='confirm_removed']").click();
}
```

Allows you to remove 100 connections at once
Make sure you load enough connections tho

**WARNING**: Be careful as you will not be asked any confirmation upon running  this script.

Comment: doesn't work as of today.

Answer (score 0):

Yep I found one,

First go to https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/

While in this page go into your console (you can press *F12* if you're on Windows, if you're mac you can go to inspect).

In your console type this:

```js
setInterval(() => {   
  document.querySelectorAll("[data-control-name=ellipsis]")[0].click()
  document.querySelectorAll("[type=trash-icon]")[0].click()
  document.querySelectorAll("[data-control-name=confirm_removed]")[0].click()
}, 500);
```

Then press *Enter*

Comment: doesn't work as of today